# Identify and remove duplicated list elements by their colnames in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, duplicates

I have a large list object which contains correlation matrices with colnames and rownames, but some of these matrices in the list appears more than once in a different order. How do I remove the duplicates without altering the matrix form or list names?

```
> my.list
$list1
  A B C
A 1 8 5
B 8 1 2
C 5 2 1

$list2
  B A C
B 1 8 2
A 8 1 5
C 2 5 1

$list3
  C A B
C 1 5 2
A 5 1 8
B 2 8 1

$list4
  X Y
X 1 9
Y 9 1

$list5
  Y X
Y 1 9
X 9 1
```

I would like to be able to match the colnames/rownames of the matrix list and remove ones appearing more than once, I'm expecting the output below

```
$list1
  A B C
A 1 8 5
B 8 1 2
C 5 2 1

$list4
  X Y
X 1 9
Y 9 1
```

I have tried the codes below but it doesn't do the job

```
my.list[!(duplicated(my.list)
```

Comment: can you share `dput(my_list)`?

Comment: I tried it and it gave the same output as my_list without taking out the duplicates

Comment: Yes, this is for sharing your data, otherwise people cannot test answers

Answer (score 1):

You can order the columns and rows according to their names, and then use `unique`:

```r
lapply(my.list, \(x) x[order(row.names(x)), order(colnames(x))]) |> 
  unique()
# [[1]]
#   A B C
# A 1 8 5
# B 8 1 2
# C 5 2 1
```

I used your first two elements as example:

```r
list1 <- read.table(header = T, text = "  A B C
A 1 8 5
B 8 1 2
C 5 2 1")

list2 <- read.table(header = T,text = "  B A C
B 1 8 2
A 8 1 5
C 2 5 1")

my.list <- list(list1, list2)
# [[1]]
#   A B C
# A 1 8 5
# B 8 1 2
# C 5 2 1
# 
# [[2]]
#   B A C
# B 1 8 2
# A 8 1 5
# C 2 5 1
```